# Transforming XML to HTML form

Tags: c#, html, xml, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create form in HTML from XML documents?

For e.g. I have the following XML:

```
 <record>
    <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
    <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
    <StudentLevel>Junior</StudentLevel>
    <StudentType>InState</StudentType>
    <HasScholarship>N</HasScholarship>
    <Action>CodeA</Action>
  </record>
  <record>
    <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
    <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
    <StudentLevel>Sophomore</StudentLevel>
    <StudentType>InState</StudentType>
    <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
    <Action>CodeB</Action>
  </record>
  <record>
    <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
    <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
    <StudentLevel>Freshmen</StudentLevel>
    <StudentType>OutOfState</StudentType>
    <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
    <Action>CodeC</Action>
  </record>
  <record>
    <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
    <IsGraduating>Y</IsGraduating>
    <StudentLevel>Senior</StudentLevel>
    <StudentType>International</StudentType>
    <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
    <Action>CodeD</Action>
  </record>
```

And I want to create an HTML form from the above XML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>IsEnrolled</td>        
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsGraduating</td>        
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>StudentLevel</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>Freshmen</option>
                    <option>Sophomore</option>
                    <option>Junior</option>
                    <option>Senior</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>StudentType</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>InState</option>
                    <option>OutOfState</option>
                    <option>International</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HasScholarship</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <span id="Action">Display the Action here based on the selected answers above</span>
</body>
```

The Action element in XML is the output to the questions. I want to display this output in the  element based on what is selected in the HTML form.

Is this possible? If so how should I approach this?

Comment: map the xml to an entity graph, then inject it to a view template, btw your question is too broad

Comment: @InvernoMuto could you point me to any resource to entity graph mapping? I understand this is a broad question, but I wanted to know if this was possible and how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not have many details this is a starting point to get what you need; we can imagine a hypothetical index action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
```

This is your xml string, if there is not a root node, you can easily add it on the fly

```
          var xmlInput = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" ?><CustomData><Records><record>
                        <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
                        <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
                        <StudentLevel>Junior</StudentLevel>
                        <StudentType>InState</StudentType>
                        <HasScholarship>N</HasScholarship>
                        <Action>CodeA</Action>
                      </record>
                      <record>
                        <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
                        <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
                        <StudentLevel>Sophomore</StudentLevel>
                        <StudentType>InState</StudentType>
                        <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
                        <Action>CodeB</Action>
                      </record>
                      <record>
                        <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
                        <IsGraduating>N</IsGraduating>
                        <StudentLevel>Freshmen</StudentLevel>
                        <StudentType>OutOfState</StudentType>
                        <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
                        <Action>CodeC</Action>
                      </record>
                      <record>
                        <IsEnrolled>Y</IsEnrolled>
                        <IsGraduating>Y</IsGraduating>
                        <StudentLevel>Senior</StudentLevel>
                        <StudentType>International</StudentType>
                        <HasScholarship>Y</HasScholarship>
                        <Action>CodeD</Action>
                      </record></Records></CustomData>";
```

The following is a representation of your objects to XML:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public class CustomData
        {
            [XmlArray(ElementName = "Records")]
            [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "record")]
            public List<Record> Records { get; set; }

            public CustomData()
            {
                Records = new List<Record>();
            }

        }
        public class Record
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsEnrolled")]
            public string IsEnrolled { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsGraduating")]
            public string IsGraduating { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "StudentLevel")]
            public string StudentLevel { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "StudentType")]
            public string StudentType { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "HasScholarship")]
            public string HasScholarship { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Action")]
            public string Action { get; set; }
        }
```

At this point you just have to deserialize the XML:

```
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomData));

            CustomData data;
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlInput))
            {
                data = (CustomData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

... and return it to your views

```
            return View(data);
     }
```

...now you remains only to render your model